# Convert negative decimal value into hexadecimal value

Tags: python, hex, decimal

I have the following value **-1073741819** (it is the exit value of a program). When I convert it via the Windows Calculator program into hex then I get the value **FFFFFFFFC0000005**.

But when I try it with a piece of python code then I get the value **-0x3ffffffb**.

Here the line:

```
>>> code = hex(-1073741819)
>>> print code
-0x3ffffffb
```

Why ? In the doc, I can read about the built-in function hex() the following:

> Convert an integer number (of any size) to a lowercase hexadecimal
>   string prefixed with “0x”, for example

Best regards,